# Slow execution of nested loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set each row contains some values for every 6 minutes. I am trying to replicate each row with 1 minute time difference.

Code works but execution is very slow.

```
 colnames(newDf)<- names(file)
    count <- nrow(file)

    for( i in 1:count)
    {
    for(j in 0:5)
    {
     vec <- file[i,]
     vec[[2]]<-as.character(format(time[i]-j*60, "%H:%M:%S"))
     newDf[nrow(newDf) + 1,] = vec
    }
    }

Sample input
Date    Time    X   Y   Z   
4/15/2017   23:54:00    -0.03   

Expected output

4/15/2017   23:54:00    -0.03   
4/15/2017   23:53:00    -0.03   
4/15/2017   23:52:00    -0.03   
4/15/2017   23:51:00    -0.03   
4/15/2017   23:50:00    -0.03
4/15/2017   23:49:00    -0.03
```

Comment: You might want to read the R inferno, which covers various pitfalls http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/ For example, growing a data.frame dynamically in a loop is slow in R (covered in chapter 2).

Comment: If you provide a small sample input (`dput(head(file))` is an easy, nice way to make copy/pasteable R objects) we can help you find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips for helping things run faster:

1. Don't build your data.frame as you go, pre-allocate it. `newDf = data.frame(Date = rep(NA,count*6),Time=NA,X=NA,Y=NA,Z=NA)` will make a data.frame with the correct number of rows.
2. Vectorization is your friend. You shouldn't need the internal loop because you can get  all 6 `j` elements at once. `format(as.POSIXlt("2018-04-18")-0:5*60,"%H:%M:%S")`. Because R will recycle values to make everything the same length you could use this to cut your iterations significantly.
3. If you have to build up your data.frame, look into using `dplyr::bind_rows` or, generate each batch of 6 values using `lapply` and then look into `data.table::rbindlist` for improved performance.